# SOAP Client Python zeep Не передаёт указанные headers параметры

Tags: python, soap, xmlhttprequest

Подскажите где искать причину, или как исправить это досадное недоразумение.
Формируя клиента для SOAP протокола общения с неким сервисом, создаётся объект zeep.Transport к который передаётся session=requests.Session() который нашпиговывается желаемым набором параметров в headers.

Анализ проводился при помощи подключаемого в zeep.Client плагина, который выводит исходящие запросы и входящие.

Код который билдит клиента:

```py
    import requests
    import zeep
    import zeep.exceptions
    from zeep import xsd
    import lxml.etree
    from lxml import etree
    
    # Плагин для анализа
    class SoapLoggingPlugin(zeep.Plugin):
        def ingress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation):
            print(f"SoapLog Ingress: {lxml.etree.tostring(
                                        envelope,
                                        pretty_print=True,
                                        encoding='utf-8',
                                    ).decode()
                                    }"
                  f"\nSoapLog Ingress Headers: {http_headers}")
            return envelope, http_headers
        def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
            print(f"SoapLog Egress: {lxml.etree.tostring(
                                        envelope,
                                        pretty_print=True,
                                        encoding='utf-8',
                                    ).decode()
                                    }"
                f"\nSoapLog Egress Headers: {http_headers}")
            return envelope, http_headers
    
    soap_logging_plugin = SoapLoggingPlugin()
    
    _session = requests.Session()
    
    token = "Обязательный токен"
    
    requests_headers = {
        "FNS-OpenApi-Token": token,
        "FNS-OpenApi-UserToken": '',
        # "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        # "SOAPAction": "urn:SendMessageRequest",
        # 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    }
    
    _session.verify = False  # Сервер не парится по поводу сертификата
    _session.headers.update(requests_headers)
    
    # Прокся обязательна, без неё не пускает на сервер
    _session.proxies = {"http": "127.0.0.1:3128", "https": "127.0.0.1:3128"}
    
    zeep_settings = zeep.Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)  # ,extra_http_headers=requests_headers) Тут можно ещё в одном месте подсунуть заголовки. НО тщетно
    
    _transport =  zeep.Transport(session=_session, timeout=30)
    
    _url = get_provider_url()  # Простая урл к wsdl схеме
    
    # Сам экземпляр клиента
    soap_client = zeep.Client(wsdl=npd_url, settings=zeep_settings, transport=_transport, plugins=[soap_logging_plugin])
```

Далее строим содержимое параметра для запроса.

```py
message_item = xsd.Element('Message', xsd.ComplexType([xsd.Element('{xmlns:ns0}GetTaxpayerStatusRequestV2', xsd.ComplexType([xsd.Element("Inn", xsd.String())]))]))
message_value = message_item([{"Inn": "1234567890"}])
result_1 = soap_client.service.SendMessage(Message=message_value)
```

Наблюдаем как нас бреет сервер, покуда не получил токена в headers

```bash
// Здесь то что отправляется, сначало тело, затем заголовки
SoapLog Egress: <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:SendMessageRequest xmlns:ns0="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiAsyncMessageConsumerService/types/1.0">
      <ns0:Message>
        <ns1:GetTaxpayerStatusRequestV2 xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns0">
          <Inn>1234567890</Inn>
        </ns1:GetTaxpayerStatusRequestV2>
      </ns0:Message>
    </ns0:SendMessageRequest>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
SoapLog Egress Headers: {'SOAPAction': '"urn:SendMessageRequest"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}


\\ Здесь то что получаем в ответ...
SoapLog Ingress: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Не удалось обнаружить требуемые заголовки в переданном запросе</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

SoapLog Ingress Headers: {'Server': 'nginx/1.14.2', 'Date': 'Tue, 19 Mar 2024 07:42:30 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '312', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Обратите внимание, заколовки
'SOAPAction': '"urn:SendMessageRequest"',
'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
я закоментил в своём наборе, чтобы выяснить кто их подставляет. Zeep формирует SOAPAction от используемого сервиса (`soap_client.service.SendMessage()`) и Content-Type что это XML документ

В дебагере отчётливо видно что в памяти в экземпляре клиента в транспорте лежат, установленные выше в коде, заголовки.

Помогите разобраться в причине и найти решение.